# US Embassy in Nigeria told me to pay them for my flight when applying for visa, however my visa was denied. Will they refund me my flight money back?

Tags: usa, air-travel, refunds, scams, nigeria

I understand that my visa fee will not be refunded, but I gave the clerk flight money as well. Will they refund that amount?

Comment: Who is "the clerk" ? What entity or office does "the clerk" work for? Who is "they" in the second sentence?

Comment: I never heard of an embassy getting flight tickets for visa applicants. Are you sure you were dealing with the embassy and not with a "visa service" or a scammer pretending to be either?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this looks like a scam, since it is unlikly that the US consulate would require the **direct payment to them** as a precondition for a visa applicaton acceptance. An image of the receipt (which probably doesn't exist) should be added to the question to show otherwise

Comment: I agree with Mark, it would seem you were scammed. money.stackexchange.com may help you understand how.

Comment: Did you actually visit the US embassy, or did you just meet someone who said they were acting in their behalf? How did you pay? How much? What for exactly? I would be surprised if you just had enough cash to pay for a flight to the US on you while visiting the US embassy… Lost likely you just let a scammer pretending to work for the US embassy.

Comment: I think the question should remain here as visa provisioning related scams are travel related and  common enough in some countries that the local embassies explicitly warn about them.

Comment: i agree clsing this question is a terrible idea as there is important information in it.

Comment: @Marianne013 I have removed my close vote.

Comment: @jcaron: Depending on how bold the scammer is, they *could* potentially work for the embassy; most embassies hire a lot of their staff from among the local population. This doesn't mean those employees have any powers related to issuing visas, but it does mean you could have a scammer who was a legitimate embassy employee (up until they're caught doing it, at which point, fired instantly). Even the shipped in embassy staff *could* do it, but they're generally folks who've been vetted rather more thoroughly than local hires, so it's less likely (not impossible).

Comment: "US Embassy in Nigeria told me to pay them for my flight when applying for visa": how did they tell you this?  E-mail?  Phone?  A message on a website?  Something else?

Comment: @ShadowRanger it’s definitely a possibility, that’s why I asked  where/who/why, etc. I still believe it to be quite unlikely compared to other scams, but if it was indeed someone working at the embassy it should be reported (another reason for the “how”, to find out if there is any proof, but I’m pretty sure the answer is cash).

Comment: Where did you apply? The US consulate to Nigeria's visa page is https://ng.usembassy.gov/visa  We can trust this because it's a .gov TLD. This links to  https://www.ustraveldocs.com  , a third-party processor. Other processors are used, for example in South Africa it is  https://ais.usvisa-info.com   Any other website, unless linked form a .gov TLD is almost certainly a scam. Do NOT trust websearchs for "US Visa application", etc. Although the major search engines are clamping down on scam visa sites (and other official government application sites), it's a game of whack-a-mole

Comment: Assuming that you have been scammed, the good news is that your visa application may not even have been submitted to the US, in which case you may still be able to get a visa by applying directly to the genuine US embassy (see comment from CSM).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others have said, this appears to be a scam, and you should contact your bank to see if there is any chance of tracing or retrieving your funds.

If you paid cash that is a red flag all by itself and the money is almost certainly irretrievably gone.

If you are still interested in traveling to the United States, the visa application process is outlined at https://ng.usembassy.gov/visas/

For applicants within Nigeria, the above linked page shows that

> In the country you selected, visa applications and interview scheduling are primarily facilitated by a third-party company, U.S. Travel Docs. Please visit their website at: https://www.ustraveldocs.com for additional information on determining what visa type is best for you and how to apply.

[Digging further](https://www.ustraveldocs.com/ng/en/payment-options), I find that as of 2024 the nonrefundable visa application fee is payable online directly to that handling company or in person via a specific form at a GT Bank branch.

In particular note that, the US Department of State has issued a fraud warning about scammers targeting US Visa applicants: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/fraud.html which says (about the Diversity Visa process) in part

> Also avoid visa consultants who charge money because they claim they
> can improve your chances of winning.  We do NOT work with consultants
> and they CANNOT improve your chances of being selected.

and also

> Some websites and emails try to mislead customers and members of the
> public into thinking they are official U.S. government websites. These
> websites are designed to appear official, and often have images of the
> U.S. flag, U.S. Capitol, White House, or Statue of Liberty. What these
> websites and emails are missing is the “.gov” suffix on their
> addresses.  Remember that anything that does not end with “.gov”
> should be considered suspect

While there appear to be a variety of legitimate visa assistance services (in general, charging a fee to help you fill out your visa application correctly and with an eye to a successful outcome) and travel agents that also offer visa services in Lagos and elsewhere in Nigeria, the legitimate ones would not claim to be US Embassy staff, and US Embassy staff do not arrange commercial flights.

Note: It's not completely impossible that you purchased a nonrefundable plane ticket from a legitimate travel agency, who attached proof of round trip airfare to a visa application they submitted on your behalf to improve your chances of acceptance. (While this is a common misconception, the US State Department directly states [Do not make final travel plans or buy tickets until you have a visa.](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html)) Even if you were merely confused into thinking that you were dealing directly with the US Embassy, in that case you should have a receipt where you signed your acceptance of such terms -- and having signed those terms, you would have no recourse, and the money is equally gone.

Comment: Logically, why would the USA care if they gave you a visa and you had no flight ticket? No problem for them.

Comment: @xLeitix most countries, including the US, have realized that some people who are determined to overstay their welcome are willing enough to throw away the return portion of a round-trip ticket.  A booking is meaningless; a ticket only slightly less so.  At https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html#apply the US State Department says "do not make final travel plans or buy tickets until you have a visa."

Comment: @xLeitix The misconception that a ticket is necessary for the visa application is precisely what makes people vulnerable to this scam.  We should be correcting the misconception, not perpetuating it.

Comment: @phoog If you say so. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Added that quote and link to the page at State; thanks, @phoog

Answer (score 63):

> US Embassy in Nigeria told me to pay them for my flight when applying for Visa, however my visa was denied. Will they refund me my flight money back?
> ...
> but I gave the clerk flight money as well. Will they refund that amount?

This looks like a scam. I doubt you will ever see the money again.

A US visa is issued by a US consulate (or consulate department inside an embassy).

It is **not** their task to book or accept payments for flights as a precondition for a visa applicaton acceptance.

Even if they did, they would issue a receipt which would **clearly state** US government (in some form) and the reason the payment was accepted for.

I doubt that you have such a receipt.

If you do have a receipt, then add an image of it into the question. The question could then be passed on to another stackexchange site that may be more helpful than travel.stackexchange.

Comment: ... in the unlikely event of having a receipt to upload, of course the OP should black out any personal information first.

Comment: What justifies the hostility from the initial vote to close the question to the demand to upload a receipt? The gist of your answer seems correct but you can make your point, even ask whether the OP has a receipt without being so hostile.

Comment: @Relaxed - This "hostility" appears to me to be something you are reading into the initial comment and this post. I don't see it. Maybe you consider bold font to be hostile? It is intended merely to emphasize important points, to make sure they are not overlooked: the requested action is not something an embassy employee should be doing, and official government documents will be clearly stated as such. It is too late to save HisMainEvent from this scam, but making sure they are aware of warning signs may help them avoid future ones.

Comment: @Relaxed There was never any hostility from my side. Without a receipt no one can give a proper answer as to how to start the process of getting a refund. An image would show details that could lead to a more precise answer.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Beside the tone or bold font, “I doubt that you have such a receipt” is what I consider hostile. Instead of a requesting info, Mark constantly expresses disbelief of what questioners say. “Are you sure you're dealing with the US embassy, you should have receive a receipt, if you haven't you have probably been scammed” is a helpful answer, “Scan the receipt or I won't believe you” is not.

Comment: @Relaxed - The questioner never claimed to have a reciept, so saying it is unlikely they have one is not in any way expressing a disbelief in what the questioner said. The reason for doubting that they had a receipt was because the information given suggests this is a scam, making it unlikely they would have gotten one. And Mark Johnson has expressed why he requested an image both in the post and in his reply to your comment, and it had nothing to do with proving the questioner's claims. (But I agree the OP should black out any personal info if they post it.)

Comment: @Relaxed If it is a scam, which is most plausible and hence likely, it is simply not a Travel SE question. (Or maybe, as the comments indicate, it is *ex negativo.*) Yes, I sometimes perceive close votes as hostile, in particular if they concern my own questions. ;-) But they are more a technical measure to keep focus.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Precisely, if you believe it's unlikely they have gotten a receipt, it doesn't make sense to ask them to scan it. Indeed, I also believe there is no point in asking for the receipt and I still don't see how it could help write a proper answer. Instead, a constructive comment would explain what exactly Mark expects to find on the receipt and invite the OP to post this information on the relevant website.

Comment: Instead, he is asking in a commanding tone to go through the trouble of scanning, editing, and uploading a receipt he doesn't believe exists and add it to a question he doesn't intend to answer and argues shouldn't even be there. You cannot tell me this is not a very hostile way to treat someone who has probably been the victim of a scam.

Comment: In written English, terse, matter-of-fact statements without the inclusion of politeness markers are **more likely to be interpreted as hostile or rude.** 
The lack of audible and visual cues such as tone of voice and facial expressions means that written language can only be interpreted by word and grammar choice. 
Writers can choose to include a few extra words or change phrasing slightly to reduce the likelihood that others will perceive rudeness without sacrificing conciseness. There's no obligation to do so, but equally, no obligation for readers to give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I have a photo of the receipt that says non-refundable